# Simple way to connect together two car alternators such that power flow can be bidirectional?

Tags: power-supply, alternator

As I understand, it's not good to power a vehicle with two alternators, unless those alternators are protected in some way so that their voltage outputs don't go unstable (and die). I have an engine with an internal and external alternator, where the internal Ducati alternator provides 10-20A and the external Denso alternator can provide 30-40A. Both alternators are "dumb", and put out a voltage ~14V.

The alternators positive leads are connected with a diode, separating the internal components from the external components. This way either alternator can power the critical engine components but only the external alternator can do things like recharge the battery, power non-engine electronics, etc...

[image]

The problem is that if the external alternator dies, the internal alternator cannot supply any energy at all to the rest of the vehicle. So a certain degree of redundancy is lost.

However, without the diode the internal alternator would die if it tried providing all the peak load to the external loads. It can happily supply the average load, but not the peak. So if the battery can step in to supply peak, then the 20A alternator can provide continuous power.

Is there a simple way to modify the section with the diode, so:

- the power can flow bidirectionally
- the 20A alternator cannot provide more than its rated capacity
- there aren't any concerns about the alternator regulators competing

---

Due to project requirements, nothing can be altered outside of the line connecting the two alternators together. Ant components I use have to be as simple as the diode. The diode can be supplemented or replaced, but that's all. I hope there still are enough degrees of freedom to solve the problem of providing bidirectional power flow.

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat & should be continued in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148793). As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat now, please.** When someone has enough information from the chat to post an answer, please answer it as usual. Any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question, not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: (The default system message when comments are moved to chat, didn't completely apply to this situation so I have replaced it with a clearer version above - for anyone who noticed the change. Instead of comments, please use the chatroom from now on, to keep relevant information in one place. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

Install a voltage sensing relay between the battery and the least essential external loads.  set it to turn off at around 13.2V on the battery terminals.

If you can't put it there put it where the diode is and accept the risk of your battery bring destroyed.